# How do I update a boolean field to its opposite in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

So I have this function:

```
async function update_subscription_status(id) {
    await User.updateOne({chat_id: id}, {
        mailing: // need to change this boolean field to its opposite       
    })
}
```

Is there any way to do it without checking its state before updating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/)

[$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/)

[$eq](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) returns true or false

```
async function update_subscription_status(id) {
    await User.updateOne(
      { chat_id: id },
      [ { "$set": { "mailing": { "$eq": [false, "$mailing"] } } } ]
    )
}
```